# How do you map an array using Polymer's dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm currently trying to map an array of strings I have to its corresponding object... but cannot find a way to do the map it.

I want to do something like this below (I know syntax is not correct, but trying to get my point across)

```
// user.connections ["1","2","3"]
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{user.connections}}" as="connection"
            map="isAppConnection" observe="app.id">
 {{connection}} <!-- The actual object -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)

```
<dom-module is="some-element">
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{isAppConnection(user.connections)}}" as="connection">
    {{connection}}
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "some-element",
    properties: {user: Object},
    isAppConnection: function(connections){
       connections.map(e=>SomeObj[e])
    },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, as long as `user` is a dependent property and `user.connections` is not undefined.